# What if rollback fails in SAGA transaction

Tags: microservices, saga

Let's imagine the situation, then we have distributed transactions in microservices, managed by [SAGA approach](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) . Out transaction exists of calling service A, then service B, then service C.

The scenario which fails:

- Service A completed the task successfully and sent the message to B
  service
- Service B completed the task successfully and sent the message to C
  service
- Service C fails and sends a message to service B to undo the
  transaction.
- Service B tries to undo the transaction but fails.

As the result, we have inconsistent data, which is unacceptable.
The question is, how to deal with the case when the transaction rollback fails in SAGA pattern?

Comment: It will need to retry until it is successful.

Comment: If inconsistency is unacceptable, including during the period while waiting for a retry of saga rollback, you can eliminate the inconsistency by killing services A and B until such time as the inconsistency can be rectified (Consistency over Availability).

Answer (score 1):

- Service B retries immediately but fails
- Service B retries after few seconds but fails
- Service B retries after few minutes but fails
- Message is moved to "dead letter queue" because it wasn't marked as processed by Service B
- Engineer fixes the bug on service B
- Engineer resends message from "dead letter queue"
- Service B handles message successfully

Read more on this topic https://codeopinion.com/handling-failures-in-message-driven-architecture/